# Polymer: ternary operator vs tokenlist?

Tags: filter, polymer, ternary

[Polymer expressions](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/expressions.html) allow you to write *ternary operators*. There is also a *tokenList* filter that can be used specifically on the *class* attribute.

It seems to me that the following two render the same thing.

ternary operator:
    `<my-element class="{{ conditional ? 'some-style' : '' }}"></my-element>`

tokenList filter:
    `<my-element class="{{ {'some-style': conditional} | tokenList }}"></my-element>`

I see authors of [Topeka](https://github.com/Polymer/topeka-elements/blob/master/topeka-categories.html) using ternary operators exclusively for *id* attributes, reserving tokenList filters for *class* attributes. I was just wondering if it's okay to use ternary operators in all circumstances; or if there's any special circumstances in which one is favored over the other.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I have many boolean properties and I have to apply classes based on their value. If I use ternary operators, it would look like this

```
<my-element class="{{a? 'a': ''}} {{b?'b':''}}...{{z?'z': z}}"></my-element>
```

But with tokenList, it would just be a simple object being parsed by tokenList

```
<my-element class="{{ {a:a, b:b, c:c, ... z:z} | tokenList }}"><my-element>
```

You can see it's really useful for classes since you can have many classes within an element.

Side note though, ***tokenList*** and other filters or the filter syntax itself are not available anymore in Polymer 0.8 and up. You can use [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) instead.